# AngularJS $window: how can it be beneficial in unit testing? (compared to using window)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

While the official docs says,

> While window is globally available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is a global variable. In AngularJS we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing.

I still cannot make sense of it.  How can I benefit from `$window` in my unit tests code? In my snippet below, I can spy/mock and make use of the native window object, with or without `$window`. How does it cause testability problems?

```
angular.module('messagePopper', [])
  .factory('popper', function popperFactory($window) {
    return {
      popupMessage(message) {
        alert(message);
      },

      popupMessageWith$window(message) {
        $window.alert(message);
      }
    };
  });

describe('messagePopper: popper service', () => {
  let $injector;
  let $window;
  let popper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    module('messagePopper');

    inject((_$injector_) => {
      $injector = _$injector_;
      $window = $injector.get('$window');
      popper = $injector.get('popper');
    });
  });

  it('should popupMessage correctly', () => {
    const message = 'welcome glenn@foodie.net';

    const alertMock = spyOn(window, 'alert');

    popper.popupMessage(message);

    expect(alertMock)
      .toHaveBeenCalledWith(message);
  });

  it('should popupMessageWith$window correctly', () => {
    const message = 'welcome glenn@foodie.net';

    const alertMock = spyOn($window, 'alert');

    popper.popupMessageWith$window(message);

    expect(alertMock)
      .toHaveBeenCalledWith(message);
  });
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/glenn/x42uex66.

Comment: there is not much [**about it**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/window.js#L45) in the first place

Comment: @AlekseySolovey yep, I've seen that under the hood as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using the global window object works, there might be times where a test will fail, causing the windows object to not be cleaned up for the next test. In which case you would suddenly see a lot of tests failing for seemingly no reason, instead of just the one test that caused the issue.